# How to Pass data from @EActivity to @EFragment and assign to view

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-annotations

I am trying to pass a simple `String` from @EActivity to @EFragment , so i can later on assign that value to textView in @EFragment , I don't want to use saving in bundle pattern

**My attempt:**

```
@EActivity(R.layout.activity_pre_plan_detail)
public class PrePlanDetailActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    // some long adapter code

    @AfterViews
    void inits_(){
       adapter.addFragment( myFragment_.builder().build().setme("something"));
    }
}
______________________________________________________________________________

@EFragment(R.layout.fragment1)
public class PlanDescription extends Fragment {

    @ViewById
    TextView tv_fpd_description;


    public void setme(String data){
        tv_fpd_description.setText(data);
    }

}
```

**output/error:**

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
```

**Note:** All mentioned annotations are part of boilerplate library `[android annotation][1]`

Comment: obviously `tv_fpd_description` is null before it is injected(I bet on `onCreateView`) ... onCreateView is not called before Fragment is added to Activity ...

Comment: so where i should initialize it then

Comment: Naive solution: check if view is null in setme ... if it is then store data somwhere and set it in @AfterViews of the Fragment ... or use setme after `adapter.addFragment`

Comment: I have carefully read the documentation of AA and then wrote this , but if textView cannot be initialized why they give it for global use in @EFragment in first place

Comment: thanks a bunch rather simple solution @Selvin

Answer (score 1):

```
Try with local broadcast manager 
**Activity code:**
-----------------
Intent intent = new Intent("my-custom-event");
        intent.putExtra("message", "something");
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(intent);

**fragment code:**
-------------------
 @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getActivity()).registerReceiver(onReceiver , new IntentFilter("my-custom-event"));
    }
 @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getActivity()).unregisterReceiver(onReceiver );
        super.onDestroy();
    }
**BroadCastReceiver:**
```

---

```
 private BroadcastReceiver onReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String data= intent.getStringExtra("message");
           tv_fpd_description.setText(data);
        }
    };
```

Comment: its nice , strategy but i prefer to use AA

Answer (score 0):

You should really use a `Fragment` argument for this:

```
@EFragment(R.layout.fragment1)
public class PlanDescription extends Fragment {

    @FragmentArg
    String someDescription;

    @ViewById
    TextView tv_fpd_description;

    @AfterViews
    void afterViews() {
        tv_fpd_description.setText(someDescription);
    }
}
```

And you can create the `Fragment` like this:

```
PlanDescription_.builder().
    someDescription("your data")
    .build();
```